# ¿Cómo retornar un JPanel desde un metodo para agregarlo a otro JPanel?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, tengo un JFrame y tengo un boton que al hacer click sobre el tiene que crear un JPanel y agregarlo a otro JPanel que tiene un layout tipo FlowLayout pero no lo agrega bien, aparecen unos pequenos cuadros.

```
public JPanel videoGUI() {
    video = new JPanel();
    video.setLayout(null);
    video.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,255));
    video.setSize(240, 350);
    titleLabel = new JLabel(this.title);
    genreLabel = new JLabel(this.genre);
    yearLabel = new JLabel(this.year);
    playButton = new JButton();

    titleLabel.setBounds(20, 279, 100, 26);
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    titleLabel.setForeground(new Color(74,74,74,255));

    genreLabel.setBounds(20, 317, 60, 15);
    genreLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    genreLabel.setForeground(new Color(74,74,74,255));

    yearLabel.setBounds(80, 317, 32, 15);
    yearLabel.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    yearLabel.setForeground(new Color(74,74,74,255));

    playButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("imgs/playButton.png"));
    playButton.setBounds(160, 277, 65, 65);

    playButton.setBorder(null);
    playButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    playButton.setBorderPainted(false);

    video.add(titleLabel);
    video.add(genreLabel);
    video.add(yearLabel);
    video.add(playButton);
    return video;
}
```

Aqui es donde creo el objeto desde la clase en la que esta el JPanel.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Video vid = new Video();
    vid.setTitle("Thor");
    vid.setGenre("Action");
    videoPanel.add(vid.videoGUI());
    videoPanel.updateUI();
}
```

Asi es como los agrega al hacer click al boton.
[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El layout manager `FlowLayout` toma los componentes y los agrega en una linea, si el espacio horizontal es muy reducido como para ubicar todos los elementos entonces multiplica las lineas y re-acomoda. Hasta aquí todo claro.

La razón por la que se ven tan pequeños los paneles es porque `FlowLayout` toma en cuenta es el `preferredSize` del componente, si a `video` le modificas el `setSize()` por `setPreferredSize()` se podrán ver los paneles con las dimensiones especificadas, en este caso: `video.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(240, 350) );`

Comment: muchas gracias, ya tenia varios dias con este problema y no sabia como solucionarlo. Otra cosa, al agregar varios JPanels llegan al maximo ancho y los pasa a otra fila, hay alguna forma de agregarle un slider horizontal para evitar esto?

Comment: Si, puedes poner el panel del `FlowLayout` dentro de un `JScrollPane`.

Comment: wow muchas gracias de nuevo, ya esta solucionado. Saludos :)